# Is it possible to combine multiple angular apps under one login?

Tags: angular

I have multiple standalone angular apps. Is it possible to create another app or consolidate all of them where you can have one login which leads to a page with redirects to each app? They can be on different domains. Or is it best to combine all of the apps into one?

Answer (score 2):

Probably can't be done safely using only redirects. Instead you could have one central server for serving auth requests for all other servers/apps. Other servers would relay login requests to the auth server and pass a jwt or other token, which the auth server returns, back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but the best way is to combine into one.

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot I guess